# Windows 10: can't edit hosts, can't grant Administrator access to edit it, can't uncheck readonly mode

Tags: windows-10, hosts-file

I can't edit `%WinDir%/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` running `notepad` as Administrator and have no antivirus software running at the moment *(it doesn't seem I have virus/malware, because I've just run Kasperski Antivirus scanner + AVAST + doctor web scanner)*, and my user is in the`Administrators` group:

1. `notepad`: [image: Screenshot1]
2. `notepad` says I have no access rights: [image: Screenshot2]
3. Can't change access rights: [image: Screenshot3]
4. Tried changing access rights to `etc` and `hosts`, but it says I can't even watch existsing access rights: [image: Screenshot4]

Comment: Give your user full access ACLs of `hosts` [Admin: `icacls %WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts /grant %UserName%:F` || `icacls $env:WinDir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts /grant ${env:UserName}:F` ] and `etc` should be reverted to its original ACLs, as no directories within `%WinDir%` should have their ACLs modified for a number of reasons _(security and it's pointless since they will be reset whenever `Sfc /ScanNow` is run)_; there are only a handful of files within `%WinDir%` that can have their ACLs modified without issue, mainly the user-configurable files within `%WinDir%/System32/drivers/etc`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method.

1. First open the hosts as txt.
2. Then click **File** -> **Save As**
3. Then select All Files and type the name **"hosts."** (or you just save as txt, and then delete the extension) to save **in another directory.**
4. Then you can `delete` the **original hosts** file and `put` the **new hosts** file to replace the **original hosts** file.
5. Now you can **edit** the **hosts**, and you can set its permissions.

[image]

Comment: This is a really convoluted answer when all that needs to be done is executing within an Admin terminal: `icacls %WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts /grant %UserName%:F ` || `icacls $env:WinDir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts /grant ${env:UserName}:F`